# PowerBI - Cumulative diagram with changing values

Tags: powerbi

I am attempting to create a cumulative graph much like this one:

[image: cumulative graph]

I have the following table in PowerBI

BugHistory

- BugID
- Date (date)
- DateTo (date)
- EntityStateName (text)
- Effort (number)

I would like to do a measure that would tell me the amount of summed Effort on any given date for each EntityState.

I have tried quite a few things, even adding a Date Table using the Calendar, but getting the values to be shown correctly on a StackedGraph seems to be beyond me.
Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following steps:

1. Right click on the column "Effort" and click the option called "New quick measure" in the right click menu.
2. In the window that appears, choose "Running Total" under the Calculation drop-down
3. This will show 3 new fields
4. In the Base Value field, drag and drop the "Effort" column
5. In the Field column drag and drop the "Date" column.
6. In the direction column choose Ascending

This will create a new measure in your Table. You can use that measure in you chart.

You can refer to the following video for reference: https://youtu.be/KlXclbN4oWE?t=497